# Cannot enter router get in express

Tags: node.js, express, get, router

I am trying to use routers in my Node js application. I cannot execute `router.get` functiom
In the main file which is server.js I used this script

```
// Routes
app.use('/api/v1/stores', require('./routes/stores'));
```

But in the route file which is stores.js, I cannot enter the router.get function and execute it

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

console.log("I can reach this point")

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log("I can not reach this point")
    res.send('app/about');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: In the console I just got: 
I can reach this point

Comment: Enjoy :)

https://github.com/AmirAltakroori/Testing-Routes.git

Comment: Does it print "I can not reach this point"!!!

Comment: yes `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/stores` hit this `URL`

Comment: It works finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because new express version 4.17.* is different when handling routes. try,

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('app/about');
});

module.exports = app;
```

For more details: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

you can try this way also, in your store.js file create something like this.

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('app/about');
    });
}
```

and add this require to server.js

```
require('./store')(app);
```

Comment: I still have that problem and I cannot print "I can not reach this point" statement

Comment: see now. I forgot to add module.exports

Comment: Also, I added it but there is no change.